# Large WordPress E-Com Site - Very slow performance (High volume of Post Meta data and Order Data)

Tags: mysql, linux, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-com store running on WordPress (Together with using WooCommerce) - We've operated the site for around 4 years now, and in that time, our website has grown heavily in sales and customer signups which is great, although, the downfall, is that our website has become extremely slow in many areas (This includes executing tasks such as, editing products from the backend of the store, and from the perspective of how our customers navigate through our website and complete their orders.

I think the challenge here, is that over time, a great amount of postmeta data and usermeta data has been building up in the MySQL database, and in result, it's caused a real downfall in performance, in which is causing multiple issues across our site with regards to loading times.

To be exact:

- Our postmeta database table is made up of ~3,554,802 rows
- Our usermeta database table is made up of ~2,759,005 rows
- Finally, woocommerce_order_itemmeta is made up of ~1,343,448 rows

Many of the other tables we have present in our db are generally within the six figures region, in terms of row count.

Whilst I know we could go ahead and delete old data (e.g. Old order data etc), could anyone recommend an alternative approach to resolving the performance issue, without deleting data?

I've seen articles which have advised to use an indexing plugin, for indexing the db tables where the row count is high, however, the last time we tried this approach, our database corrupted (But we had a backup on standby ready to restore)

I know there is a lot of posts/articles out there in regards to WordPress bloating, which comes with large amounts of metadata and postdata being built up within the db, but is there any recommendations e.g. Alternative db engines/systems which are more suited for processing larger quantities of data?

Or perhaps any recommendations based around performing optimisations to our current db for the faster processing of db tables with large row counts? (As a way of speeding up page load time)

MySQL DB Server Specification:

- We are currently running our DB on a remote database server and we are using MySQL 8.0.

Server Specification:

- Bare Metal Server
- CPU:16 Core x 3.0 GHz (AMD Epyc 7302P)
- RAM:128 GB
- NVMe2 x 960 GB Hardware RAID 1

Comment: Do you have this installed?  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: Please note this has been migrated to ServerFault.com Question 1152315 as of 2024 01 17 ~ 13:00 GMT